# Handling page loading with Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have a variable handling page loading with true or false. If all data is ready, a loading icon is hidden and the rest of the page shows up then 'loading' the variable is 'false'.

I run multiple functions to retrieve data from a data base in `Promise.all()` to make sure all data is ready.

However, there is a time lag between the variable change and the page change. It takes about 10 secs to show the rest of the page even if  all data is ready and 'loading' variable is 'false'.

```
$scope.load = true;

function getData1(){
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         //this is http call from Customer Service
         Customer.getCustomers().then(function(data){   
             if (data.data.success) {
                $scope.customers = data.data.customers; 
                resolve(true);          
             } else {
                 reject(false);
             }
        })
     })
}
function getData2(){
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         //this is http call from Event Service
         Event.getEvents().then(function(data){   
             if (data.data.success) {
                 $scope.events = data.data.events; 
                 resolve(true);         
             } else {
               reject(false);
             }
         })
     })
}
.
.
.
Promise.all([getData1(), getData2(), getData3()])
    .then(results=>{
        $scope.load = false;            
})
```

If I place `$scope.load = false` in each functions it can be solved but it does not make sense to put `$scope.load = false` in all functions instead of placing it in `Promise.all()` only once.

```
 function getData1(){
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         //this is http call from Customer Service
         Customer.getCustomers().then(function(data){   
             if (data.data.success) {
                $scope.customers = data.data.customers;
                $scope.load = false;
                resolve(true);          
             } else {
                 reject(false);
             }
        })
     })
}
```

Can anyone explain why the time lag happens in this case?

---

I do not see any loops or anything in the functions which take 10 seconds to go through. When I put `console.log(results[0]) console.log(results[1]) console.log(results[2])` inside of `Promise.all()` it shows immediately that the promises are resolved.

Comment: How can this work when `getData1()` is calling itself immediately and unconditionally? Are you sure this is your code? The final version of `getData1()` does not have this recursive call. I suppose the first one is wrong? Or where do you get your DB job done?

Comment: @trincot  Sorry it's my bad I meant http call from services so I changed the parts. Customer.getCustomers() and Event.getEvents() do the job for DB and if they both succeed I want to stop loading and show the rest of the page.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No there is no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not see any loops or anything in the functions which take 10 seconds to go through. When I put `console.log(results[0]) console.log(results[1]) console.log(results[2])` inside of `Promise.all()` it shows immediately that the promises are resolved.

The ES6 promises created by `Promise.all()` are not integrated with the AngularJS framework execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Instead use `$q.all`:

```
̶P̶r̶o̶m̶i̶s̶e̶.̶a̶l̶l̶(̶[̶g̶e̶t̶D̶a̶t̶a̶1̶(̶)̶,̶ ̶g̶e̶t̶D̶a̶t̶a̶2̶(̶)̶,̶ ̶g̶e̶t̶D̶a̶t̶a̶3̶(̶)̶]̶)̶
$q.all([getData1(), getData2(), getData3()])
    .then(results=>{
        $scope.load = false;            
})
```

Also avoid using ES6 promise constructors:

```
function getData1(){
    ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶P̶r̶o̶m̶i̶s̶e̶(̶(̶r̶e̶s̶o̶l̶v̶e̶,̶ ̶r̶e̶j̶e̶c̶t̶)̶ ̶=̶>̶ ̶{̶
    //this is http call from Customer Service
    return Customer.getCustomers().then(function(response){   
        if (response.data.success) {
            $scope.customers = response.data.customers; 
            return $scope.customers;          
        } else {
            throw "getCustomers failed";
        }
    })
}
```

The `getCustomers()` function already returns a promise, so there is no need to construct an ES6 promise that is not integrated with the AngularJS execution context and its digest cycle.

Comment: Yes it's working with $q.all!!! Thank you so much. You made my day.